# AutoHotKey stop working after I started PowerShell as administrator

Tags: powershell, autohotkey

I use the AutoHotKey script to map some the keys under Windows 10 OS . It works very well except that I started Powershell as administrator. All the key mappings does not work after that as if autohotkey has been shut down. However things are all fine when I run PowerShell without administrator. Anyone knows how to fix that?

Comment: What happens if you also run AutoHotKey as an administrator? AutoHotKey may not be able to pick up on the key combinations from an administrative window.

Comment: @Bluecakes You are right about this.  I used to try setting AutoHotKey to run always as administrator but I've got two versions of AutoHotKey.exe on my computer and I always run ahk script with the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

As  Bluecakes said, just running the AutoHotKey as administrator will fix my problem.

You can either set the AutoHotKey to run always as administrator by right-click on AutoHotKey.exe and select property, in the compatiblity Tab , check the run this programme as administrator, or you can add a 'run as administrator' entry in the right-click menu of ahk scripts by editting the registry. Following this [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-run-as-administrator-for-autohotkey-scripts-in-windows-vista/):